# First time user of Galleria and i just can't get it to work?

Tags: javascript, galleria

First time user of Galleria and i just can't get it to work? its just giving me a list of images?
i have tried what it says in the FAQ's but nothing is working? please can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't no Galleria but the following code

```
jQuery("#gallery").galleria({
```

is referring to an element with id="gallery".

I think the second div

```
<div id="gallery/landscapes (random)">
```

Should read:

```
<div id="gallery">
```

Answer (score 0):

Going to the page directly, I see a couple things that might help.

- You are loading the theme both at the top, and in your script
- You might need to load the script later on in the document, since the div has to exist before it can reference it.  (On the page up on the web, the script comes *before* the gallery div.  It needs to come after it)
- The code posted here has the incorrect div name (`"gallery/landscapes (random)"`), but the one on the site has the correct name (`"gallery"`)